# Identity Server redirect to React Native error

Tags: react-native, identityserver4

I have an Identity Server running.

I try to make an authentication from a React Native App.

I am using [react-native-app-auth](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth) package to do authentication.

When I do login from the app, I have the Identity Server Login page that is loaded in a browser.
When I login with the good credential, Identity Server return me an error "The view 'Redirect' was not found..."

Do you know What's missing ?
I expect to be redirected to my app after success login ...

Here is my config:

**Identity Server config :**

```
public static Client GetMobileClient()
        {
            return new Client
            {
                ClientId = "mobile.code",
                ClientName = "Mobile Client (Code with PKCE)",
                RequireClientSecret = false,
                RedirectUris = { "com.server.acc:/oauthredirect" },
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                RequirePkce = true,
                AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile" , "email", "api.read" },
                AllowOfflineAccess = true
            };
        }
```

And here is my React Native Config:

**Build.gradle**

```
manifestPlaceholders = [ appAuthRedirectScheme: 'com.server.acc' ]
```

**Login.tsx:**

```
import { authorize, refresh, AuthConfiguration } from 'react-native-app-auth';
...

const config: AuthConfiguration = {
            issuer: 'https://acc.server.com:44344',
            clientId: 'mobile.code',
            redirectUrl: 'com.server.acc:/oauthredirect',
            scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email', 'api.read']
        };
          
const authState = await authorize(config);
```

So once I do "await authorize(config);", we have the login page that is loaded, after putting the good credentials, I have this error :

[image]

Why is he looking for **.cshtml** pages ???

Many Thanks ! I am blocked during 3 days for this !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure ,but perhaps you should add **HTTPS://** infront of the URL here:

```
redirectUrl: 'com.server.acc:/oauthredirect',
```